# Any javascript library which can parse string created by Intl.DateTimeFormat?

Tags: javascript

Is there any javascript library which can parse string created by Intl.DateTimeFormat and give a Date?

For example:

```
  options = {
      year: "numeric",
      month: "short",
      day: "numeric",
      hour: "numeric",
      minute: "numeric",
      weekday: "short",
      }
  var test_date = new Date();
  console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('hr', options).format(test_date));
  // note that test_date is just an example. 
  // We need to parse text created Intl.DateTimeFormat and give a Date.
```

will return:

```
sub, 21. ožu 2020. 12:41
```

That is great - exactly how it should be written.

But how to parse it back to be a Date?

Something like:

```
 Date.parse('sub, 21. ožu 2020. 12:41', options, 'hr') 
 // hr is locale
 // options are same a options given to Intl.DateTimeFormat
```

We tried momentjs and format 'llll', but sadly momentjs locale are different that Intl.DateTimeFormat implementation on Google Chrome (i.e., dots are added in wrong places, abbreviations for dates are incorrect, etc.). We tested with 'hr', 'sk', and few others and no luck :(

So is there any library which any javascript library which can parse string created by Intl.DateTimeFormat?

Comment: @StefanAvramovic We wanted to parse it back to Date object. I have updated the question.

Comment: Why do you need to parse it back? Just keep `test_date`.

Comment: @kosh Test_date is just an example. Anyway, the point is that text we are parsing is not created by our javascript (i.e. running as an extension or doing text scraping).

Comment: Looks like your question is missing those details. If that text was not created by you, what makes you think that it was created with `Intl.DateTimeFormat`? If you're making an extension or scraping (what exactly?), there may be another approach. Please update your question to describe your situation better.